# Subgroup H group G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $N:=\cap_{x\in G} \ \ x^{-1}Hx$. Prove, that $N$ is normal subgroup in $G$.

I did this:

Let $g\in G$.

Whether $g(xhx^{-1})g^{-1}\in N$?

Take $f=gx$.

$g(xhx^{-1})g^{-1}=(gx)h(x^{-1}g^{-1})=(gx)h(xg)^{-1}=fhf^{-1}\in N$, because $f\in G$, when $f\in G$ and $gx\in G$

So, $g(xhx^{-1})g^{-1}\in N$, so $N$ is normal subgroup $G$.

Is this argument is ok?

Comment: Can you use *words* to explain where all the variables are coming from, and why you're performing certain calculations? I think the work is fine, it's just not clear what you're doing or why. Like with the line after $g \in G$, you say "$g(xhx^{-1})g^{-1}\in N$". Is this what you ultimately want to show, or are you asserting that it's clearly the case?

Comment: You might consider using more words. For example, when you say 'Let $g \in G$. $g(xhx^{-1}) g^{-1} \in N$.' it is not clear whether you mean that if $g \in G$, then $g(xhx^{-1}) g^{-1} \in N$ (which is not yet true as you are supposed to prove this right now) or that you wanted to say something like 'we have to show $g(xhx^{-1}) g^{-1} \in N$ for any  $x \in G$ and $h \in H$'.

Comment: Ok, I edit my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help you to see a more verbose proof.

First, we notice that the elements of $N$ are such that no matter which conjugation we apply to $H$, they are going to be there. So:
$$
N=\{n\in H:\forall x\in G\ \exists h\in H\ st\ x^{-1}hx=n\}\subset H
$$
So now we are all set to prove the normality of $N$. We are going to pick an arbitrary conjugation of $N$ and see that it coincides with $N$.

That means, let $g\in G$ and $n\in N$. Is it true that $g^{-1}ng\in N$?

By our definition of $N$, $g^{-1}ng$ would have to satisfy that $\forall x\in G\ \exists h\in H\ st\ x^{-1}hx=g^{-1}ng$.
Let $x\in G$. Is it true that $\exists h\in H\ st\ x^{-1}hx=g^{-1}ng$?

We notice here that this last condition is equivalent to $\exists h\in H\ st\ gx^{-1}hxg^{-1}=(gx^{-1})h(gx^{-1})^{-1}=n$, which is automatically fulfilled since $n\in N$.

Thus we conclude that $N$ is normal.